# Trying to rotate my customCells imageView on willDisplayCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

So, I am trying to rotate my custom cell's imageView at the willDisplayCell part and something strange happens, image shows weirdly. This is what I have:

```
firstCellAnimated *cell2 = (firstCellAnimated*)cell;
[cell2 turnImageView];
```

This is turnImageView function:

```
self.imageViewCustom.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45);
```

If I run that function somewhere else it shows up fine. So could someone help me to figure what is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `imageView` on a `UITableViewCell` is managed by the cell, rotating it is likely to not be dealt with well.  I'd suggest adding your own `UIImageView` subview of the cell if you want to perform non-trivial manipulations on it.

Comment: Great idea, I will try it ASAP. But I wonder why it only bugs in willDisplayCell and not in anywhere else?